# Instagram API EndPoint "/tags/tag-name/media/recent" doesn't return videos from android correctly

Tags: android, api, video, instagram

I'm experiencing a very strange problem with Instagram API.

When I post a video width a specific tag from an Android device, I can't get it from the API EndPoint "/tags/tag-name/media/recent".

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?client_id={client-id}

This is not a private/public problem, because my photo are returned correctly with this EndPoint.
Furthermore my videos are returned correctly whith an other API EndPoint "/users/user-id/media/recent"

The strange thing is that when I do exactly the same thing with an IOS device, i get my videos correctly with the API EndPoint "/tags/tag-name/media/recent".

Thank you,
Yoann.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting Instagram developers, the problem is now fixed.